# Material Chips in table list

Tags: tables, material-design, data-tables, readability, alignment

should the chips fill all the table cell width for clear alignment or is better to align them as they were a text element for better readability?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is just an observation (no research), but the text readability seems about the same in either case.

All the chips are left aligned, so I can scan the column vertically and see the avatars and the names. Everything lines up in either choice.

[image]

Plus, if you're sticking to the 'chips' component, it's normal to see chips of varying widths.